# SphinxQL  RT index error

Tags: sphinx

I have tried with sample example using Sphinx QL source code. But i am getting "No Data Base Selected" error. Can anyone share the sample Example? it will be very useful for me..

Sphinx QL wrapper class has downloaded from following path:
 http://code.google.com/p/sphinxapi/source/browse/trunk/class.sphinxql.php?r=2

using following steps:

```
$option['host'] = 'localhost';
$classApi = new SphinxQL($option);
$value = $classApi->exec(" select count(DISTINCT ID) from tablename where fanme=2769457");
```

> ERROR : No Database Selected

Answer (score 0):

As noted on the sphinx forum
http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=9864

looks like there are a couple of errors in that code you found.